# SDN 4 Session.query doesn't work for @QueryResult

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

In my SDN 4 project I have a `@QueryResult` POJO:

```
@QueryResult
public class WeightedDecision {

    private Decision decision;

    private double weight;

    public Decision getDecision() {
        return decision;
    }

    public void setDecision(Decision decision) {
        this.decision = decision;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(double weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

}
```

And a lot of Spring Data Neo4j repository methods that work fine with this `WeightedDecision` query result.

Right now I'm trying to manually construct a Cypher query where I'm going to return the list of `WeightedDecision` as a result.

I use following method for this purpose:

```
return (List<WeightedDecision>) session.query(WeightedDecision.class, cypher, parameters);
```

my Cypher query looks like:

```
MATCH (parentD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) WHERE id(parentD) = {decisionId} OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)<-[:VOTED_FOR]-(vg:VoteGroup)-[:VOTED_ON]->(c:Criterion) WHERE id(c) IN {criteriaIds} WITH childD, ru, u, vg.avgVotesWeight as weight  RETURN childD AS decision, ru, u, sum(weight) as weight ORDER BY weight DESC
```

but the result of `session.query` is empty in this case.

If I'm changing the `session.query` method parameters to:

```
return (List<WeightedDecision>) session.query(Decision.class, cypher, parameters);
```

where `Decision` is a Node Entity everything works fine and returns List of Decision.

How to get it working with a `@QueryResult` type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@QueryResult is not an OGM concept and hence is not supported by the OGM Session.

It is only supported on repository queries.

Comment: How to execute this query from code in order to get a @QueryResult ? Is any chance to reuse the logic from repository queries(I mean the logic under the repository query hood) in order to do this ?