# Should I expect Neo4jOperations#queryForObjects to work with @QueryResult POJOs?

Tags: spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

`Neo4jOperations#queryForObjects()` doesn't seem to play well with `@QueryResult` POJOs - it always says that result set is empty.

Trying `Neo4jOperations#queryForObjects` - it says result is empty:

```
@Test
public void thisDoesNotWork() {
    Iterable<ClassNodeIdAndName> result = neo4jOperations.queryForObjects(
            ClassNodeIdAndName.class,
            "MATCH (c:ClassNode) RETURN ID(c) AS id, c.name AS name",
            new HashMap<>());
    assertTrue(result.iterator().hasNext());
}
```

Trying `Neo4jOperations#query` - says result is NOT empty:

```
@Test
public void thisWorksFine() {
    Result result = neo4jOperations.query(
            "MATCH (c:ClassNode) RETURN ID(c) AS id, c.name AS name",
            new HashMap<>());
    assertTrue(result.iterator().hasNext());
}
```

Trying repository with `@Query` - says result is NOT empty:

```
@Test
public void thisWorksFineAsWell() {
    List<ClassNodeIdAndName> classNodeIdsAndNames = classNodeRepository.getAllIdsAndNames();
    assertFalse(classNodeIdsAndNames.isEmpty());
}

public interface ClassNodeRepository extends GraphRepository<ClassNode> {
    @Query("MATCH (c:ClassNode) RETURN ID(c) AS id, c.name AS name")
    List<ClassNodeIdAndName> getAllIdsAndNames();
}

@QueryResult
public class ClassNodeIdAndName {
    public Long id;
    public String name;
}
```

[Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-neo4j/current/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/template/Neo4jOperations.html#queryForObjects-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-) says that

> Iterable queryForObjects(Class **entityType**,
>
> **entityType** - The Class denoting the type of entity to return

But I'm confused whether I should look at **type of entity** or at **for objects**. If it's not supposed to handle `@QueryResult`, I would expect it to throw instead of returning no results.

I'm using spring-data-neo4j 4.1.3.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@QueryResult` is a [Spring Data Neo4j](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j) concept that applies only to Spring `Repository`s.

`Neo4jOperations` is a thin wrapper around the [Neo4j OGM](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm)'s `Session` class and consequently does not handle the concept of returning query result objects.

Also see: [SDN 4 Session.query doesn't work for @QueryResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916323/sdn-4-session-query-doesnt-work-for-queryresult)

Comment: Well, how thin is "thin"? Compare `Neo4jOperations` to `JdbcOperations`  - both are supposed to be thin wrappers, but `JdbcOperations` introduces concepts like `ResultSetExtractor` and `RowMapper`. I don't see how it's different from `Neo4jOperations` with its `@QueryResult` - both are pretty much "tools that make data extraction easier".

Comment: `Neo4jOperations` is more akin to `HibernateOperations` or `JpaOperations`. The former is only around for legacy reasons while the latter has already been deprecated and removed from Spring.  If there was a parallel for `JdbcOperations` it would be for the actual drivers: embedded, http and bolt.